# how to compare three numbers with if-else

Tags: python

```
#take three integers and sort with if-else

a, b, c = map(int, input("insert 3 integers : ").split())
print("assign check : ", a, b, c)

if a > b & a > c:
    print(f"{c, b, a}" if c < b else f"{b, c, a}")
elif b > a & b > c:
    print(f"{a, c, b}" if a < c else f"{c, a, b}")
elif c > a & c > b:
    print(f"{a, b, c}" if a < b else f"{b, a, c}")
else:
    print("wrong code!!!")
```

I'd like to sort 3 integers with if-else(I know sort() is exist but my professor want me to use if - else) but if I type 10 2 5, "wrong code!!!" is printed out.

Comment: First thing to note is that logical-and in python is `and`, not `&` though I'm uncertain it matters here.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski It does matter because of operator precedence. `a > b & a > c` is equivalent to `a > (b & a) > c`

Comment: oh thank you for helping! & was bitwise..It's diffrent from other languages.

Comment: Swapping numbers looks like a simpler solution
if a > b:
   // swap a and b
if a > c:
   // swap a and c
if b > c
   // swap b and c

now a < b < c

Comment: @pedro1798 Other languages use `&&` for logical, `&` is still bitwise.

Comment: Another thing you may want to note is equal cases, like input `1 1 40`. Therefore, for more inclusive cases, make all comparisons contain = (i.e change > to >=, etc.)

Comment: yeah I used && but It errors so I tried &, it worked and I thought & is python's boolean lol..I wondered if python can chain comparative operators, thank you!

Comment: If you want to know if `a` is greater than both `b` and `c` you could write `b < a > c`

Comment: thank you for helping me to make better code everyone!! I'll add equal cases and make it go well.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski wow it's way easyier to see

Comment: Another strategy would be `biggest = max(a, b, c)` then do `if biggest == a` etc.

Comment: Another strategy `', '.join(c for n, c in sorted(zip([a, b, c], 'abc'), reverse=True))`. This pairs numbers with letter using `zip`, sorts them largest to smallest, and then takes just the letters.

Comment: Oh I'll try these methods! there's lots of handful skills I don't know. I'll note them!!

Answer (score 0):

i made an image to make you understand the probabilities of the final value.

[This is the probabilities of the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCbRM.png)

i do not know if i have mistacs or not i am very lazy to check . please check and tell me.

```py
A , B , C = map(int,input("insert 3 integers :").split())

if A > B and A > C:
    print(A)
    if B > C:
        print(B)
        print(C)
    elif C > B:
        print(C)
        print(B)

if B > A and B > C:
    print(B)
    if A > C:
        print(A)
        print(C)
    elif C > A:
        print(C)
        print(A)

if C > A and C > B:
    print(C)
    if A > B:
        print(A)
        print(B)
    elif B > A:
        print(B)
        print(A)
```